# Insert object into JSON object

Tags: php

I am trying to add a json object to an object downloaded from my database, but when I add the object it doesn't really sit at the same location in the object, it adds every additional object as a child of the first. Please see below.

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [component] => fork
            [date_] => 06/08/2019
            [servicetype] => rtyrtyrty
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [component] => fork
                    [date_] => 20/05/2019
                    [servicetype] => rtyrtyrty
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [component] => fork
                    [date_] => 10/02/2019
                    [servicetype] => rtyrtyrty
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [component] => fork
                    [date_] => 11/12/2018
                    [servicetype] => rtyrtyrty
                )
        )
)
```

What I have been trying is converting the original object to an array using json_decode() then using the push function: array_push($array1, $array2); I can't seem to avoid getting the above result.

```php
  originalObj= json_decode($newObj);
  array_push($originalObj, $newObj);
  $encodeForServerUpload = json_encode($originalObj);
```

Comment: Use `array_merge` instead of `array_push`.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON?

Comment: Can you please print_r your JSON object downloaded from Database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$originalObj= json_decode($newObj);
array_push($originalObj, $newObj[0]);
$encodeForServerUpload = json_encode($originalObj);
```